# Deleted file reappears when running from commited Docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The following is a simplefied example of the problem I am facing.

In short: A file I am deleting from a Docker container reappears after I commit the initial container and create a new one from the commited one.

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

VOLUME /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY docker-entrypoint-initdb.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY delete-me.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup/

ENTRYPOINT "docker-entrypoint.sh"
```

I setup a VOLUME and COPY some files into the container.

*docker-entrypoint.sh* => the actuall entrypoint as seen in the Dockerfile

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

docker-entrypoint-initdb.sh && exec /bin/bash -c "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"
```

*docker-entrypoint-initdb.sh* => Script containing the commands that should be run when creating the container. (In my real world project some of these should always run and some only on the first time. The script basically iterates over the folder */docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup/* and runs all scripts inside of it.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup/delete-me.sh
rm -R /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup/ 2> /dev/null
```

*delete-me.sh* => This file contains logic that should only run the first time a container is created from this image. In all subsequent run's this file would destroy the data and render the container unusable.

```
echo DELETE_ME
```

The container is build using the comman `docker build -f Dockerfile -t ubu-test`.

And run with `docker run -d ubu-test`.

After I run the container for the first time it is setup correctly. The script *delete-me.sh* runs and than gets deleted by *docker-entrypoint-initdb.sh*.

I `docker commit` the container after the frist run.

Now the problem: When I create a new container from the commited one the file *delete-me.sh* is present again.

I don't understand why. (I confirmed it was deleted in the container I commited by `docker exec -it` into it. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is being caused by the volume. As specified in the [docs for docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#extended-description):

> The commit operation will not include any data contained in volumes mounted inside the container.

The Docker commit will commit the containers filesystem changes into a new image. Since `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` is a volume,
all files changes done under this directory won't be part of the commited container, since volumes are not stored in the copy-on-write
filesystem that stores the container.

As a solution, you can either remove the `VOLUME` declaration from the Dockerfile.

Alternatively, give the volume a name and reuse it as such:

```
docker run -v initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d -d ubu-test
```

Comment: Thank you! Not sure how I consistently missed this in the docs. Thank you for pointing it out!